# For django-storages and GCE, how do you set the GS_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

For django-storages and google compute engine (GCE), how do you create and set credentials for a web application?

Here is the current documentation: http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html

Answer (score 5):

To save someone else time, I'm re-posting the answers that [driesdesmet](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/455#issuecomment-360288072), [sww314](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/455#issuecomment-360288072), and [manufont](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/455#issuecomment-380798743) added to 2 separate github issues

**Step 1** (driesdesmet)

`pip install google-cloud-storage`

**Step 2** (sww314)

Follow steps 1, 2, and optionally 4 here (not step 3):

https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/455#issuecomment-360288072

**Step 3** . (manufont)

Instead of:

```
GS_CREDENTIALS = "path/to/credentials.json"
```

Do this:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "path/to/credentials.json"
)
```